# How to avoid powershell going into wait mode automatically

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which automates the upload of a report. After the file upload dialog box opens in Internet Explorer, My code tries to get it's id and then send keys and send the file address and sendkeys enter. But unfortunately as soon as the file upload dialog box pops up my script doesn't proceed further and waits there. If I hit close (in the file upload dialog) then the script continues. Is there any way by which I can tell powershell to not wait for anything? 
Here's my code :-

```
$dummy = get-process iexplore | where {$_.mainWindowTitle -eq "ArkAngelWeb - Hitachi Systems Security Inc. - Internet Explorer"} | select -expand id
Sleep 1
$temp = $ie.Document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName("v-button-caption") | Where-Object {$_.innerHTML -eq "Select file"}
$temp.click()
Sleep 2
$swshell=New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$fileUploadDialog = get-process iexplore | where {$_.mainWindowTitle -eq "ArkAngelWeb - Hitachi Systems Security Inc. - Internet Explorer" -and $_.Id -ne 
$dummy.Id} | select -expand id 
$swshell.AppActivate($fileUploadDialog.Id)
$swshell.SendKeys("H");
$swshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
$swshell.SendKeys("C:\Users\ratns1\Desktop\TEST_FILE.txt")
$swshell.SendKeys("~")
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure all of this UI manipulation is necessary? Can you use `Invoke-WebRequest` or [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).as) to put your file in the required location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the issue with SendKeys, timing, UI controls, etc.

You are popping a model dialog box, and that is what's causing the wait. 
By design, your script will not continue until you dismiss it. This is the design for dialogs.

PoSH notwithstanding, it is your use case that is the catch 22, not PoSH itself.

Take a look at the Wasp module to take the load off all the sendkey and Window lookup stuff off your plate.

> Occasionally, the only way of automating processes is to send
>   keystrokes or mouse clicks to UI elements.  A good and free PowerShell
>   extension is called "WASP" and is available here:
>
> ```
> http://wasp.codeplex.com/
> ```
>
> Once you install the module (do not forget to unblock the ZIP file
>   before you unpack it, via right-click,  Properties, Unblock), the WASP
>   module provides the following cmdlets:

```
Get-WindowPosition
Remove-Window
Select-ChildWindow
Select-Control
Select-Window
Send-Click
Send-Keys
Set-WindowsActive
Set-WindwowPosition
```

> Here is a simple automation example using the Windows calculator:

```
Import-Module WASP 

# launch Calculator
$process = Start-Process -FilePath calc -PassThru
$id = $process.Id
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$window = Select-Window | Where-Object { $_.ProcessID -eq $id }

# send keys
$window | Send-Keys 123
$window | Send-Keys '{+}'
$window | Send-Keys 999
$window | Send-Keys =

# send CTRL+c
$window | Send-Keys '^c'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. When I download WASP, it doesn't have a psm so PoSH can't find that module. please guide me. I am sorry but I am a beginner with PoSH

Comment: your answer looks promising, but I want to use this script on a corporate laptop and my laptop doesn't allow me to copy anything to the modules folder. Is there any other way to solve this issue without a 3rd party module? Thanks

Comment: No module has to be in the module folder to use it. It can be anywhere. It's just recommended to put things there because it is already in the system and powershell paths. Remember, though .psm1 is the normal way to represents a module, it does not have to be called that. it can be a .ps1 file. As long as the foldername, script name and you use the module path, or a unc to the location or dot sourcing. You can use them. Example: --- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As noted, a module does not have to be called .psm1. A module can be a .dll, or .ps1 file as well. The Import-Module command is not looking for a .psm1 file specifically. It is looking for a folder and file of the same name. Just put it anywhere and do the full path to the location. Like this --- Import-Module -FullyQualifiedName 'F:\Scripts\PoSHTools\WASP'. Then see the commands with this; Get-Command -Module wasp

Comment: Sounds cool. I'll update u as I try it tomorrow morning. Just a heads up that I wasn't able to find a dll eother when I looked in that zip. But I'll try the way you suggested and let you know. Thank you wo much for baring with me and helping me. I owe you a big one

Comment: No worries. Note there are two sets of files on that site. One is the source code. That is not what you want. The other is module folder, There is only one folder with 3 files in it. 2 .ps1 and 2.dll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165585/discussion-between-shez-ratnani-and-postanote).